# Awesomium IWebview ResourceInterceptor c#

Tags: c#, event-handling, awesomium

I want use multiple views to use in Awesomium but It has ResourceInterceptor in WebCore common usage i cannot assign ResourceInerceptor separately,
How to achive

```
    List<myBrowser> browsers = new List<myBrowser>();
       WebCore.Started += (se, ea) => { 
       WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new myResourceInterceptor(); 
        };
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
         WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(folder + "\\b" + i,new WebPreferences());
         WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768, session, WebViewType.Window);
         myBrowser b = new myBrowser(folder + "\\b" + i,ref view);
         b.view.Source = "www.google.com".ToUri();
        }




    public class myBrowser
    {
      .. .
     public myBrowser(string data,ref WebView view)
      {
          this.dataFolder = data;
          this.view = view;
          view.LoadingFrameComplete += view_LoadingFrameComplete;            
       }
    }

   // I can get unique WebViewId (request.ViewId) how to route this event to correct "myBrowser"
   public class myResourceInterceptor: IResourceInterceptor
    {
      public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
      {
        Console.Write("Request"+request.ViewId); 
      }
    }
```

I can get unique WebViewId (request.ViewId) in IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest 
how to route this event to correct "myBrowser" instance

Or is there a better way to achive this need ?

I wish to get an answer this time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to route it back to the correct instance manually.  The mybrowser instance, or websession that sent the request will get the response back when you return a ResourceResponse in the OnRequest method.  If for some reason you really need the MyBrowser instance, keep a Dictionary of ViewId,MyBrowser instead of just a List of MyBrowser, then you can index the browser you want. The viewid should be in the webview you create.